# I am trying to make a json array after getting each records from a grid. I want to add row number of grid as key of each row in json array

Tags: extjs

I am trying to make a json array after getting each records from a grid in ExtJS 3.4.0. I want to add row number of grid as key of each row in JSON array.

```
var selected_value = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    var rec = store.getAt(i);
    selected_value[i] = rec.data;
    final.push({
        "i":selected_value[i],
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do there is build an array of objects with each object containing one property called i and that property has the value of the row in it.

I guess you actually just wanted to have an array with the row objects in it, right?

```
final.push(selected_value[i]);
```

This will do the job already. No need to specify an object with associative indices.

If you're grabbing all the store's entries already or at least know the range (start and end index) you could just as well skip all the manual item picking and grab a readymade array already:

```
final = store.getRange();
```

or

```
final = store.getRange(from, to);
```

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem, please accept my answer.